# PHP upload file on server not working

Tags: php, upload, server

I made a webpage based on HTML,JS,CSS,PHP and MYSQL.
When i open the site local on my Mac, everything seems fine.

Now i tried uploading it to a webserver with the newest php version.
The site is working except the uploading.
Its a shoe shop, and i as an admin should be able to change the pictures of some articles and because i want to have a shoe in different colors, i had to upload 9 pictures for every view of the shoe (sounds stupid but i want it like that).

Strange is, that i can only upload 25files at one time. everything after 25 is getting an error for "undefined index xx" and so on.

Is there a way to unlock the max uplaod files on a server?

Comment: You're probably running into the server's limit on the post input size.

Comment: Show us the code that's not working

Comment: i dont think so, because i also tried to send the form without uploading anything. There is no error with the first 25 empty entries. But it gives errors on the rest...

Comment: It also depends on what kind of server you are on. Are you on a shared environment or are you able to access php.ini for modifications?

Comment: i have checked the server. Doesnt seem like i cant see such a file...